Ошибка связанная с "libcrypto-3-x64.dll"и"libssl-3-x64.dll"
я прохожу курс по С++ и на уроке на котором обьясняли как подключить mysql через mysql-connector к C++ при запуске программы мне видало ошибку "The code execution cannot proceed because libssl-3-x64.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." и "The code execution cannot proceed because libcrypto-3-x64.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.".
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

const string SERVER = "tcp://localhost:8889";
const string USER = "root";
const string PASSWORD = "root";

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    sql::Driver* driver;
    sql::Connection* conn = nullptr;
    sql::Statement* stmt;
    sql::PreparedStatement* pstmt;

    try {
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        conn = driver->connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException& ex) {
        if (conn != nullptr && !conn->isClosed())
            conn->close();
        cout << "Connection error. " << ex.what();
        system("pause");
        exit(1);

    }


    conn->close();

    return 0;
}

Ниже прикреплю скрины


Крайне сильно прошу вашей помощи

Положите их рядом с Вашим *.exe в директорию сборки - \bin\release\x64, куда у Вас студия настроена

Сообщение об ошибке указывает на отсутствие файлов libcrypto-3-x64.dll и libssl-3-x64.dll. Эти файлы являются частью библиотеки OpenSSL, которая необходима для использования MySQL C++ Connector.
Для исправления подключения к БД:
Скопируйте файлы libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll и libssl-1_1-x64.dll в папку проекта x64/Release. Это позволит разместить файлы рядом с исполняемым файлом программы.
Альтернативный вариант: Разместите DLL-файлы в папке System32.
Загрузить необходимые файлы и ознакомиться с другими вариантами решения проблемы можно по ссылке: https://www.openssl.org/source/
Важно: На сайте указано, что для 64-битных систем DLL-файлы необходимо размещать в папке syswow64.
